# Force People Picker to Search Across Several Forests

Tags: 2010, 2013, people-picker

Is it possible to force people picker to search across two different forests?

In this example I enable search within only one forest:

```
stsadm -o setapppassword -password P@ssw0rd
stsadm -o setproperty -url 'http://portal'  -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:contoso.ru,spfarm,P@ssw0rd;domain:contoso,spfarm,P@ssw0rd"
Set-SPSite -Identity 'http://portal' -UserAccountDirectoryPath ""
```

Can I, somehow, allow search across two forests at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple forests and or domains by listing multiple domains or forests in the format Forest/Domain:DnsName,LoginName,Password separated by semicolons. For e.g.

> STSADM.exe -o setproperty-propertyname peoplepicker-searchadforests
>   -propertyvalue“**forest:Contoso.com,Contoso\User1,PasswordofUser1**; **domain:Fabrikam.com,Fabrikam\User2,PasswordofUser2**” -url http://webapp

Note : You can omit the username and password if the application pool identity already has access to Target domain or forest, this would be the case where application pool identity is from the Trusted forest or domain itself .

[All you want to know about People Picker in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajank/archive/2009/09/20/all-you-want-to-know-about-people-picker-in-sharepoint-functionality-configuration-troubleshooting-part-2.aspx)