# SharePoint 2013, 1 Farm, 2 Forests, How does the people picker determine who to display from which forest?

Tags: 2013, permissions, people-picker, domain

There's a main forest (company.local), and two company forests (companyA.company.local, companyB.company.local).  I've read the post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138285/force-people-picker-to-search-across-several-forests) about making the people picker span several forests, but haven't implemented it yet.

I'm curious how this works...  On one site collection when granting permissions, the people picker can find companyA\userA, but no one in companyB.  On a separate site collection it's the reverse.  What determines which forest a site collection's people picker will search?  Is it based on the Site Collections Primary Administrator?

We have User Profile Sync importing from both forests, but I'm guessing that UPS really doesn't have any effect on people picker and user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [This](http://www.thewaltons.com.au/general/sharepoint-2013-people-picker-in-a-two-way-forest-domain-trust/) link. This issue we was facing before.

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the Stack Exchange standards. Check [answer]

Comment: Thanks Lax.  I implimented this a couple of months ago and it seems to do the job.